# how can i get response cookies with android volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am sending HTTP requests In android with Volley, the point is that when sending the request, the server responds with a Set-Cookie with a certain key and value,

How can I get this value? checking the browser network I get the following

[image]

I would like to obtain this numeric value as it is a requirement for subsequent requests.

This is my current code.

```
 StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, linklogin,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.getMessage());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user", "");
            params.put("pws", "");

            return params;
        }

    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
```

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435582/2299040

Comment: Thank you if I checked it but I did not know how to adapt it to my code with volley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class named **VolleyStringRequest** and paste the following code:

```
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Header;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class VolleyStringRequest implements Response.Listener<String> {
    ResponseListener listener;
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener;
    int method = -1;
    String url;
    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> params;

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onResponse(response, headers);
        }
    }

    public VolleyStringRequest(int method, String url, ResponseListener listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Map<String, String> params) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.method = method;
        this.url = url;
        this.errorListener = errorListener;
        this.params = params;

    }

    public VolleyStringRequest(String url, ResponseListener listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Map<String, String> params) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.url = url;
        this.errorListener = errorListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    public Request getRequest() {
        if (method == -1) {
            return new Request(url, this, errorListener);
        } else {
            return new Request(method, url, this, errorListener);
        }
    }

    class Request extends StringRequest {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return params;
        }

        public Request(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(method, url, listener, errorListener);
        }

        public Request(String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(url, listener, errorListener);
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            headers.addAll(response.allHeaders);
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    }

    public interface ResponseListener {
        void onResponse(String response, List<Header> headers);
    }

}
```

Now how to use this Class:

```
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
        StringRequest request = new VolleyStringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"https://google.com", new VolleyStringRequest.ResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response, List<Header> headers) {
//here you get all the headers. do whatever you want with it
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        },params).getRequest();
      queue.add(request);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the strange thing is that I can not get the Set-Cookie the others if: /

Comment: @DarkFenix can you give the url and credentials, I want to try it with this code

Comment: No, it is currently a private URL and susceptible

Comment: @ Sahil Manchanda how can I get the Set-Cookie if I am using a JSON object request not string request and POST method? I have an open Bounty please have a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730709/capture-cookie-from-volley-json-response

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

override this method.

```
            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                Log.e("response@@", response.headers.toString());
                Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.headers;
                String cookies = responseHeaders.get("Set-Cookie");
                Log.e("cookies@@", cookies);
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }
```

Comment: with this method I get a NullPointerException